# SSRS report runs fine in BIDS but is exteremely slow at run time

Tags: sql-server, performance, reporting-services, runtime, rendering

I have a report which runs fine in BIDS but is extremely slow when deployed and run in browser.  Query against the SQL Server db is not the issue.  The issue is that rendering is taking huge time at run time.  RS log shows that TimeRendering takes about 30 sec, TimeDataRetrieval about 1.5 sec and TimeProcessing 0.015 sec.  Any ideas how to resolve this?

I'm running this on SQL Server 2008 R2 with SP2 and Cumulative Update 10.

Thanks
Will

Comment: Is your report rendering lot of high quality images?

Comment: No, it has a bar chart with 20 bars and a pie with 20 slices.

Comment: The only thing which is a little bit different on this report is the fact that it does have two big filters each with a ~1700 multi-selectable values.  However, the drop downs are filled quickly and all queries take little time to process.

Comment: For testing, remove bar and pie chart. Instead add a table and pull the same data without any complex logic in the report. Check if the report is still slow?